# How to map input to output fileds from excel to csv in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-cde, pentaho-data-integration

How to map input to output fileds from excel to csv in pentaho?[image]

[image: desired output file]

How to tranform this in pentaho ? Where to map values of input to output columns as the positions and name are different in input to output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the fields right in your MS-Excel-Input step, and you can reorder the fields in Text-File-Output.  Also, a Select-Values step allows you to rename and reorder fields in one sweep on the Select & Alter tab.

Comment: but it would be difficult for 100s of column every time @marabu .. is the any other way where we could get output file column name in select values or any other transfoemation? btw thanks for the help...

Comment: Nothing beats a good problem description.  Right now, there's too much room for interpretation.  If you add additional requirements to your original question, or if you prefer to ask a new question, I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The `Select Values` step allows you to change the column names and position (as well as type).

Note that the column name in the `Excel Input` is arbitrary and do not need to be related to the actual name in the Excel file, so that can rename them at wish. You can even copy/paste the names into the `Field list`.

Note also that the order of the column in the CSV output file is defined in `Fields` tab of `Text file output` step. You can change it with the Ctrl-Arrows keys.

If you need to industrialize the process and have the new columns name and order in, for example, a set of files or a database table, then you need `Metadata injection`. Have a look to [Diethard's](http://diethardsteiner.github.io/pdi/2015/10/31/Transformation-Executor-Record-Groups.html) or [Jens'](http://kettle.bleuel.com/2016/04/14/pentaho-6-1-part-2/) examples.